# MGWT Forms vs pure GWT Form

Tags: forms, gwt, mgwt

What is the real difference between in forms classes provided by MGWT and pure GWT?
I'm currently developing in GWT web application with lots of forms, so I'm preparing some helper classes.
In a moment I will need also a mobile version. I've already made some steps in MGWT and I think it will suits me best in general mobile layout.
But I'm wondering about those forms.

Should I really need to prepare another set of helper classes that uses form widgets provided by MGWT or I can just use pure GWT widgets?

Going further if I can use pure GWT forms can I mix it with MGWT form item widgets for some cases?

Thanks in advance!